# Asking for other collision inside OnCollisionExit2D - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection

I have two types of grounds tagged with "groundBlack" & "groundWhite". In order to jump, I check if the collider left an object which tag starts with "ground".

```
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col){

    if (col.gameObject.tag.Substring (0, 5) == "ground") {
        playerController.grounded = false;
    }

  }
```

The problem is that each time my player moves from one to another, it sets grounded to false and I don't want to. Is there a way to know inside an OnCollisionExit2D if it is still colliding with other object tagged with ground or there is another way to do that ? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col.GetContacts` will give you all the current contacts. Hopefully it should still be populated in OnCollisionExit. Otherwise you can just keep a list of collisions: add on entry, remove on exit. Then you only set grounded to false when your list is empty.

Also, instead of `.Substring (0, 5) == "ground"` you should use `.StartsWith("ground")`. No need to allocate a new string just for a comparison.

Comment: I like the second option, very helpful! Thank a lot!